# How to fix Symfony 4 error "Not find enum type"

Tags: php, symfony4

I'm working on a visualization interface  project with PHP and Symfony.

Seeing that I am a beginner I do not really know how to find a solution on a bug. In fact when I import my Postgres database into Symfony 4 with command:

```
php bin/console  doctrine:mapping:import App\\Entity annotation --path=src/Entity
```

There is a message:

> Not find enum type

I tried to add

```
type mappign: type: srting
```

in the file `config.yml` but but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

in your file  **config.yml** add this::

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
```

source [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html)

Answer (score 0):

did what Igmer Rodriguez suggests, but the problem persists. Anyone else has suggestions? Maybe something not involving changing the Doctrine DBAL code inthe Symfony 4 bundle